# Visualizar el contenido de la base de conocimiento de PROLOG

Tags: programación-funcional, prolog, lógica

tengo una duda acerca de este programa en PROLOG que me dejaron, es acerca de que por medio de un predicado  como: **mostrar.**  me muestre todo el contenido de la base de conocimiento que es vuelo, pero la verdad que no he encontrado mucho acerca de como hacerlo mas que se podría utilizar la función dynamic de que trae por defecto prolog, pero no me funciona.

```
mostrar:- dynamic(vuelo/3).


vuelo(nueva_york, chicago,1000).
vuelo(chicago, denver,1000).
vuelo(nueva_york, toronto,800).
vuelo(nueva_york, denver,1900).



% 1.- Hacer una regla donde visualice todos los viajes.
% 2.- Hacer una regla que elimine todos los viajes de un origen.


vuelade:-write('desde '),read(A), 
               write('a: '), read(B), encontrar(A,B).

encontrar(A,B):- ruta(A,B,D), write('La distancia es de '),write(D), write(' Km.'),!, nl.

ruta(A,B,C):- es_vuelo(A,B,C).
ruta(_,_,D):- !,write('no, hay ruta para ese destino '), nl, D=0, fail, !.
es_vuelo(T,T2,D):- vuelo(T,T2,D), write(T).


agregar:-write('desde: '),read(Desde),write('hacia: '),read(H),
write('distancia: '),read(Dis),
assert(vuelo(Desde,H,Dis)).

borrar :- write('Desde: '),read(Desde), retract(vuelo(Desde,_,_)), !,
       write('vuelo Borrado').

borrar :- write('No existe este vuelo').

borratodo:- abolish(vuelo/3), write('vuelos Borrados').
```

En fin este es mi programa espero me puedan orientar acerca de como hacerlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En base a lo que definiste en el predicado `mostrar`, podrías usar [findall](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=findall/3) para obtener la información de vuelos. Por ejemplo:

```
mostrar:-
    findall([Origen, Destino, Distancia], vuelo(Origen, Destino, Distancia), Vuelos),
    writeln(Vuelos).
```

Resultado:

```
?- mostrar.
[[nueva_york,chicago,1000],[chicago,denver,1000],[nueva_york,toronto,800],[nueva_york,denver,1900]]
true.
```

Por otro lado, el predicado [dynamic/1](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(dynamic)/1) sirve para indicarle al intérprete de Prolog que la definición de un predicado puede cambiar durante la ejecución.

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias!